# OpenGL for different frameworks

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

We have two projects. One of them is PyQt application. Another project is the delphi application. Both projects must paint the same things using opengl. So, we can't use QOpenGLWidgets(there is no qt in our delphi project).

But we want to use low-level opengl API in dll and transmit HWND of QWidget to opengl. We are newbies. We can't :'(

We found an [example](https://gist.github.com/mobius/2016283) using HWND of the window to create opengl context and draw. On the next step we create QWidget, get its HWND(WinID). But functions WinProc and WinMain stopped processing messages.

Then we trying to create opengl context in qwidget constructor and call function display in QWidget.PaintEvent, but we can see picture just when we resize the window (after that standard function fills the window by white color, and we can't see our picture).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qwidget.h>

void
display()
{
    /* rotate a triangle around */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2i(0, 1);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2i(-1, -1);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2i(1, -1);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void initializeGL(HWND hWnd) {
    int pf;
    HDC hDC;                            /* device context */
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

    memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(pfd));
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;

    pf = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(hDC, pf, &pfd);
    DescribePixelFormat(hDC, pf, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), &pfd);

    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
}

void paintGL(HWND hWnd) {
    HDC hDC;                            /* device context */
    HGLRC hRC;                          /* opengl context */

    hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);

    static PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    display();
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
}

class MyGlWidget : public QWidget {

public:
    MyGlWidget() {
        initializeGL((HWND)this->winId());
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event) {
        //MyGlWidget::paintEvent(event);
        paintGL((HWND)this->winId());
    }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyGlWidget w;
    w.show();
    //w.setStyleSheet("background:red");

    return a.exec();
}
```